# Can I compare two different scores with two different maxes if I scale them to 1?

Tags: normalization

I have two scores based on the same population:

Score A has a max of 6

Score B has a max of 9

> Score A's formula is 1 * Multiplier_A * Multiplier_B + FlatNumber_A +
> FlatNumber_B
>
> Score B's formula is 1 * Multiplier_A * Multiplier_B * Multiplier_C +
> FlatNumber_B...
>
> ... Where FlatNumber_A is swapped out for Multiplier_C, resulting in a
> higher score.

Can I compare these two if I scale them to 1?

**Can I, for example, say a Score A of 4.32 is equivalent to a Score B of 6.51?
... If 4.32 / 6 = 0.72 and 6.51 / 9 = 0.72**

EDIT: The scores are based on the same underlying data features.

So for my example, FlatNumber_A and Multiplier_C are based on the same continuous numerical feature, which I'll call Count_Feature. FlatNumber_A just checks if Count_Feature is greater than 0, if so, FlatNumber_A is set to 1.

Multiplier_C checks if Count_Feature falls into any of three ranges, if so, set Multiplier_C equal to 1.33, 1.66, or 2.00 for the three ranges.

I feel that because these two scores use the same underlying features, they can be compared to each other.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"? // If they come from the same population, scaling them differently does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Dave - Just added an edit. I mean I want to know if it's acceptable to compare the two scores. They are based on the same population, the same features. It's just that one formula element in Score B was changed from a flat number to a multiplier.

So if I were to compare the two scores, my guess is that I'd have to divide the scores by their respective maxes to scale them both to 1.